# How to read inner tags with HTMLParser?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, html-parsing

Somewhere in a HTML file I have a `div` with inner tags like this:

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <h3><a href="#">TEXT</a></h3>
</div>
```

How do I find the text inside the `a` element using the HTMLParser class in Python? I want to do it with HTMLParser, not BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
"""innerlink.py - print text of e.g. `<div><h3><a>This</a></h3></div>`."""

from html.parser import HTMLParser


class InnerLinkParser(HTMLParser):

    """A parser for HTML with links in h3s in divs."""

    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.stack = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.stack.append(tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        while self.stack:
            item = self.stack.pop()
            if item == tag:
                break
        else:
            raise ValueError("unmatched closing %r tag." % tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.stack[-3:] == ["div", "h3", "a"]:
            print(data)


def parse(html):
    """Feed the parser with some HTML."""
    parser = InnerLinkParser()
    parser.feed(html)
```

Usage:

```
>>> from innerlink import parse
>>> with open("fragment.html") as f:
...     parse(f.read())
... 
TEXT
```

The `handle_endtag()` method is written to cope with the possibility of implicitly closed tags; you may or may not need that.